# Android App Using a WordPress Backend

Tags: android, wordpress

Hi I have a business directory powered by WordPress, I need an Android application that is able to use my WordPress database to search for business address and phone using an android smartphone.  What is the best approach?

Sorry if my question is not clear, but I hope you understand.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common solutions is to build a webservice in which you interact with the database, as the database isn't a local database. After this you can make request to the webservice to get the information from the database to the Android phone.

A bunch of tutorials for this already exists, and here are some:

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: Thanks mate, I will check this out. I am planning to do a native android app with phonegap searching in my wordpress database.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I was looking the tutorials, but I would like an app the could do queries in my database using search forms and things like this.

Comment: @user2295830 Android can unfortunately not connect directly to the remote database. So the second best option is to do the above.